# Implementing a desktop .NET application that can work offline. 

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, offline

I need to create a desktop WPF application in .NET.

The application communicates with a web server, and can work in offline mode when the web server isn't available.

For example the application needs to calculate how much time the user works on a project.  The application connects to the server and gets a list of projects, the user selects one project, and presses a button to start timer.  The user can later stop the timer.  The project start and stop times need to be sent to the server.

How to implement this functionality when the application is in offline mode?

Is there are some existing solution or some libraries to simplify this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider the security implications of how you cache / store the timestamps and what system you get them from. For example, if obtained from the client system, the timestamp could be spoofed. This may not be a concern for you, but you should at least be aware. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello all I implemented this application I've created my own off-line framework
based on this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714559.aspx) and Microsoft Disconnected Service Agent
[DSA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648273.aspx)

I've adapted this framework for my needs.
Thank you for all.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to do a couple of things differently in order to work offline.

First, you'll need to cache a list of projects.  This way, the user doesn't have to go online to get the project list - you can pull it from your local cache when the user is offline.

Secondly, you'll need to save your timing results locally.  Once you go online again, you can update the server will all of the historic timing data.

This just requires saving the information locally.  You can choose to save it anywhere you wish, and even a simple XML file would suffice for the information you're saving, since it's simple - just a project + a timespan.

It sounds like this is a timing application for business tracking purposes, in which case you'll want to prevent the user from easily changing the data.  Personally, I would probably save this in [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(VS.80).aspx), and potentially encrypt it.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I also thought to store data in local XML file. But I don't know how to determine when the server is available.

Comment: It sounds like this is a timing application for business tracking purposes, - Yes that is timing application.

Comment: If you have some advise please help me.

Comment: @Serghei: Just try to connect - if you get an exception, handle this locally for that run...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sql Server Compact for you local storage and then you microsoft sync framework to sync your local database to the server database. I recommend doing some research on the Microsoft Sync Framework.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I thought about SQL Server CE but the Web Server is implemented in PHP. and I don't know if the Sync Framework works with MySql and PHP Server

Comment: You could implement a WCF service on the server side that connects to mysql for synchronization part. Sync framework on the server side should be able to talk to your MySql database since its using standard ADO.net framework to do synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a typed or untyped dataset for offline-storage.
when online (connected to internet) you can download the data into a dataset and upload it back to the database server. the dataset can be loaded from and saved to a local file.